# Datasets in Mathematica

Tags: dataset, associations

I have two columns of data as two separately defined lists. I want to create a dataset and assign a key to each column. I tried this:

```
Dataset[Dates, Cases][All, AssociationThread[col, Range[Length[col]]]]
```

where "dates" and "cases" are the two columns of data and col={"date", "cases"} to be the keys, but it does not seem to be working. Any guidance on how to proceed?

The code is as follows:

```
data = Import[
   "/Users/--/Desktop/Variants_of_Concern_Technical_Briefing_23__Data_\
England-2.xlsx", "Dataset"];
vdata = Part[data, 6];
Dates = Flatten[Normal[vdata[{75 ;;}, {1}]]];
Cases = Flatten[Normal[vdata[{75 ;;}, {3}]]];

assoc = AssociationThread[{"date", "cases"} -> {Dates}, {Cases}]
```

You will need to download the [excel sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiovonV7oH3AhXOTsAKHTyjC38QFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.publishing.service.gov.uk%2Fgovernment%2Fuploads%2Fsystem%2Fuploads%2Fattachment_data%2Ffile%2F1018476%2FVariants_of_Concern_Technical_Briefing_23__Data_England.xlsx&usg=AOvVaw1OcXo1WAVh8NbtGGkW0Nf9).

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include enough Mathematica code that can be copied and pasted to a notebook, so that potential respondents can recreate your problem. It is called a `minimal working example` and facilitates focused replies. Thank you.

Comment: `Cases` is a reserved word.

Comment: Your Excel notebook has 14 sheets with multi-columnar data. To which sheet are you referring to when you say `"I have two columns of data as two separately defined lists"` ? This looks like a job for a professional consultant doing paid work.  Unless you can present a `minimal working example` and ask a specific question, your question is unlikely to receive much traction on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(* data from the 1st worksheet is retrieved *)

ClearAll[data,ds];

data = Import["/Users/--/Desktop
          /Variants_of_Concern_Technical_Briefing_23__Data_\
          England-2.xlsx", {"Data", 1}];  

ds = Join @@ Map[a \[Function] Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ 
      Rest[a]]][{data}];

(* to see the retrieved data, just run "ds" *)

ds
```