# import a data file

Tags: export, string-manipulation, import

I have 350 data files which i have exported like

```
    Do[
 Export[StringJoin[{"/home/cosmos/madhurima/differentialeq_sol/\
backwardtheta_phia=0.1b=0.6/diffsol"}, ToString[k], {"\[Phi]"}, 
   ToString[l], {".dat"}], 
  Partition[
   Flatten[Table[{t1, 
      Sqrt[(Variables[nu[[k]][[l]]][[2]] /. sol /. 
          t -> t1)^2 + (Variables[nuI[[k]][[l]]][[2]] /. sol /. 
          t -> t1)^2]}, {t1, N[10^-4], N[20*10^-4], N[10^-6]}]], 
   2]], {k, 1, 35}, {l, 1, 10}]
```

Now I want to import each of the 350 files into one table each dynamically. How to do it?

Comment: In which format are your original data files stored? What is the structure of individual data sets?

Comment: original data is in ".dat" format. Each files have 2 columns and 1901 rows and there are 350 such files.

Comment: See the answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266323/60365

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want to import data from the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd worksheets of your data file "data.xlsx". The data formats in each worksheet should be identical.
To import from three worksheets of a given `data.xlsx` file and create a dataset `dsData`:

```
ClearAll[data,data1,data2,data3,dsData];

data1 = Import["insert XLSX file address\data.xlsx", {"Data", 1}];  
data2 = Import["insert XLSX file address\data.xlsx", {"Data", 2}];  
data3 = Import["insert XLSX file address\data.xlsx", {"Data", 3}];  

dsData = Join @@ Map[a \[Function] Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ 
  Rest[a]]][{data1,data2,data3}];

dsData
```

To import data from separate xlsx files such as `veri1.xlsx`, `veri2.xlsx`, and `veri3.xlsx` with only one worksheet in each one, then you can do:

```
ClearAll[veri1,veri2,veri3, ver1,ver2,ver3, dsVer];
ver1 = Import["insert XLSX file address\veri1.xlsx", {"Data", 3}];  
ver2 = Import["insert XLSX file address\veri2.xlsx", {"Data", 3}];  
ver3 = Import["insert XLSX file address\veri3.xlsx", {"Data", 3}];  

dsVer = Join @@ Map[a \[Function] Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ 
        Rest[a]]][{ver1,ver2,ver3}];

dsVer
```

Note that in this example, importing data is from the `3rd` worksheet `{"Data", 3}` of each separate xlsx file. You may change the worksheet number at will to refer to the worksheet from which you want to import data.